# UI code-behind for managing employees

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a form code behind and it has what are called "Common Utilities".  Basically the original author made a super class that is embedded into the main form code behind.  What is the best way to refactor this?  And what methods can stay in the main form?  I think my issue is in each of these methods there are references to form objects.  For instance the LoadComboBoxes method... It makes a database call to another method that populates the comboboxes from the database... Would I, on form load, send a list of comboboxes from the form to this other class, operate on the objects and then send them back?  Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using Connolly.Lib.Controls;


namespace VendorManager
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        #region Declarations

        private string updateXML;
        private EmployeeEditMode editMode;
        private bool rehire;
        private string originalUserName;
        private string originalType;

        private enum EmployeeEditMode
        {
            Locked = 0,
            NewEmployee = 1,
            EditEmployee = 2
        }

        VM_DatabaseUtilities objConnect;
        string conString;
        string sqlStatement;
        DataSet ds;
        DataRow dRow;

        int maxRows;
        int inc = 0;

        #endregion

        #region FormEvents
        private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cmdSave.Top = cmdEdit.Top;
            cmdCancel.Top = cmdNew.Top;
            cmdDuplicate.Top = cmdRehire.Top;

            editMode = EmployeeEditMode.Locked;
            ToggleFormObjects();
            LoadComboBoxes();
            LoadEmployeeList("");
        }

        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void menuExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void menuAbout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CommonUtilities aboutConnolly = new CommonUtilities();
            aboutConnolly.ShowHelpWindow(VendorManager.Properties.Settings.Default.version.ToString(), true);
        }

        private void cmdSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            XmlUtilities xml = new XmlUtilities();
            XDocument X = new XDocument();
            Associate updateAssociate = new Associate();
            updateAssociate = BuildAssociate();
            X = xml.UpdateEmployeeXml(updateAssociate, updateXML);
            DatabaseCall(3, X.ToString());
            LoadAssociate(updateAssociate.AssocID);
            if ((txtTerminationDate.Text ?? string.Empty).Length == 0)
                radActive.Checked = true;
            else
                radTerminated.Checked = true;
            cboTypeSelect.SelectedValue = cboType.SelectedValue;
            LoadEmployeeList("");
            lstEmployees.SelectedValue = updateAssociate.AssocID;
            LoadAssociate(lstEmployees.SelectedValue.ToString());

        }

        private void cmdEdit_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            if (lstEmployees.SelectedValue.ToString().Length > 0) 
            {
                editMode = EmployeeEditMode.EditEmployee;
                ToggleFormObjects();
            }
        }

        private void cboTypeSelect_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            int filter = Int32.Parse(cboTypeSelect.SelectedValue.ToString());
            LoadEmployeeList(filter.ToString());
            cboTypeSelect.SelectedValue = filter;
        }

        private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string filter = cboTypeSelect.SelectedValue.ToString();
            DatabaseCall(0, "");
            if (filter.ToString() != VendorManager.Properties.Settings.Default.allEmployees)
                DatabaseCall(1, filter.ToString());
            else
                DatabaseCall(1, "");
            cboTypeSelect.SelectedValue = filter;
        }

        private void lstEmployees_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (lstEmployees.SelectedValue.ToString().Length > 0)
                LoadAssociate(lstEmployees.SelectedValue.ToString());
        }

        #endregion

        #region CommonUtilities


        private void LoadComboBoxes()
        {
            try
            {
                DatabaseCall(0, "");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void LoadEmployeeList(string filters)
        {
            try
            {
                DatabaseCall(1, filters);

                if (lstEmployees.SelectedIndex < 0)
                {
                    ClearAssociate();
                    cmdEdit.Enabled = false;
                    cmdDuplicate.Enabled = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    LoadAssociate(lstEmployees.SelectedValue.ToString());
                    cmdEdit.Enabled = true;
                    cmdDuplicate.Enabled = true;
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

        }

        private void LoadAssociate(string assocID)
        {
            CommonUtilities xmlEncoding = new CommonUtilities();

            updateXML = xmlEncoding.VM_EmployeeUpdateXML();

            DatabaseCall(2, assocID);

            if (dRow != null)
            {
                txtAssocId.Text = dRow["AssocID"].ToString() ?? string.Empty;
                txtFname.Text = dRow["FName"].ToString() ?? string.Empty;
                txtLname.Text = dRow["LName"].ToString() ?? string.Empty;
                txtHireDate.Text = dRow["HireDate"].ToString() ?? string.Empty;
                txtContractEnd.Text = dRow["ContractDte"].ToString() ?? string.Empty;
                txtTerminationDate.Text = dRow["TerminationDate"].ToString() ?? string.Empty;
                txtUserName.Text = dRow["UserName"].ToString() ?? string.Empty;
                cboTitle.SelectedValue = dRow["TitleID"].ToString() ?? string.Empty;
                cboType.SelectedValue = dRow["EmpStatusID"].ToString() ?? string.Empty;
                cboPRole.SelectedValue = dRow["PrimaryRole"].ToString() ?? string.Empty;
                cboLocation.SelectedValue = dRow["LocationID"].ToString() ?? string.Empty;
                cboSuperPrincipal.SelectedValue = dRow["SuperPrincipal"].ToString() ?? string.Empty;
                cboCompany.SelectedValue = dRow["CoNum"].ToString() ?? string.Empty;
                cboLOB.SelectedValue = dRow["LOBID"].ToString() ?? string.Empty;
                cboDomain.SelectedValue = dRow["SystemDomain"].ToString() ?? "W";
                cboFullPart.SelectedValue = dRow["FullPart"].ToString() ?? "0";
                txtNotes.Text = dRow["Notes"].ToString() ?? string.Empty;
                txtFirmName.Text = dRow["FirmName"].ToString() ?? string.Empty;
                txtAdpId.Text = dRow["AdpId"].ToString() ?? string.Empty;
                originalUserName = txtUserName.Text ?? string.Empty;
                originalType = cboType.SelectedValue.ToString() ?? string.Empty;
                updateXML = updateXML.Replace("{ADP}", dRow["AdpId"].ToString() ?? string.Empty);
                updateXML = updateXML.Replace("{AssocID}", dRow["AssocId"].ToString() ?? string.Empty);
                updateXML = updateXML.Replace("{oFName}", xmlEncoding.XMLEncode(dRow["FName"].ToString() ?? string.Empty));
                updateXML = updateXML.Replace("{oLName}", xmlEncoding.XMLEncode(dRow["LName"].ToString() ?? string.Empty));
                updateXML = updateXML.Replace("{oSupervisor}", dRow["SuperPrincipal"].ToString() ?? string.Empty);
                updateXML = updateXML.Replace("{oTitleID}", dRow["titleID"].ToString() ?? string.Empty);
                updateXML = updateXML.Replace("{oLocation}", cboLocation.SelectedValue == null ? string.Empty : cboLocation.SelectedValue.ToString());
                updateXML = updateXML.Replace("{oPR}", cboPRole.SelectedValue == null ? string.Empty : cboPRole.SelectedValue.ToString());
                updateXML = updateXML.Replace("{oEmpType}", cboType.SelectedValue == null ? string.Empty : cboType.SelectedValue.ToString());
                updateXML = updateXML.Replace("{oTermDate}", dRow["TerminationDate"].ToString() ?? "1900-01-01T00:00:00");
                updateXML = updateXML.Replace("{oCoNum}", dRow["CoNum"].ToString() ?? string.Empty);
                updateXML = updateXML.Replace("{oNotes}", xmlEncoding.XMLEncode(dRow["Notes"].ToString() ?? string.Empty));
                updateXML = updateXML.Replace("{oStartDate}", dRow["HireDate"].ToString() ?? "1900-01-01T00:00:00");
                updateXML = updateXML.Replace("{ICContractEnd}", dRow["ContractDte"].ToString() ?? "1900-01-01T00:00:00");
                updateXML = updateXML.Replace("{oFirmName}", xmlEncoding.XMLEncode(dRow["FirmName"].ToString() ?? string.Empty));
                updateXML = updateXML.Replace("{oFT}", dRow["FullPart"].ToString() ?? "0");
                updateXML = updateXML.Replace("{oLOB}", dRow["LOBID"].ToString() ?? "0");
                updateXML = updateXML.Replace("{oSystemDomain}", dRow["SystemDomain"].ToString() ?? "W");
                updateXML = updateXML.Replace("{oUserName}", dRow["UserName"].ToString() ?? string.Empty);
            }

            //BuildAssociate();
        }

        private void ClearAssociate()
        {
            txtAssocId.Text = null;
            txtFname.Text = null;
            txtLname.Text = null;
            txtHireDate.Text = null;
            txtContractEnd.Text = null;
            txtTerminationDate.Text = null;
            txtAdpId.Text = null;
            txtUserName.Text = null;
            cboTitle.SelectedIndex = -1;
            cboType.SelectedIndex = -1;
            cboPRole.SelectedIndex = -1;
            cboLocation.SelectedIndex = -1;
            cboSuperPrincipal.SelectedIndex = -1;
            cboCompany.SelectedIndex = -1;
            cboLOB.SelectedIndex = -1;
            cboDomain.SelectedIndex = -1;
            cboFullPart.SelectedIndex = -1;
            txtNotes.Text = null;
            txtFirmName.Text = null;
        }

        private void ToggleFormObjects()
        {
            bool isLocked = false;

            lstEmployees.Focus();
            cmdEdit.Visible = false;
            cmdNew.Visible = false;
            cmdSave.Visible = false;
            cmdCancel.Visible = false;
            cmdRehire.Visible = false;
            cmdDuplicate.Visible = false;

            switch (editMode)
            {
                case EmployeeEditMode.Locked:
                    {
                        isLocked = true;
                        cmdEdit.Visible = true;
                        cmdNew.Visible = true;
                        cmdDuplicate.Visible = txtTerminationDate.Text.Length == 0;   //setup isnull type of thing

                        break;
                    }
                case EmployeeEditMode.NewEmployee:
                    {
                        cmdSave.Visible = true;
                        cmdCancel.Visible = true;

                        break;
                    }
                case EmployeeEditMode.EditEmployee:
                    {
                        cmdSave.Visible = true;
                        cmdCancel.Visible = true;
                        cmdRehire.Visible = true;

                        break;
                    }
            }

            lstEmployees.Enabled = isLocked;
            radActive.AutoCheck = isLocked;
            radTerminated.AutoCheck = isLocked;
            cboTypeSelect.Enabled = isLocked;
            txtAdpId.Enabled = !isLocked;
            txtAssocId.Enabled = !isLocked;
            txtFname.Enabled = !isLocked;
            txtLname.Enabled = !isLocked;
            txtHireDate.Enabled = !isLocked;
            txtTerminationDate.ReadOnly = (isLocked == true || cboTypeSelect.SelectedText.ToString() == "Regular");
            cboSuperPrincipal.Enabled = !isLocked;
            txtContractEnd.Enabled = !isLocked;
            cboCompany.Enabled = !isLocked;
            cboTitle.Enabled = !isLocked;
            cboLocation.Enabled = !isLocked;
            cboType.Enabled = !isLocked;
            cboPRole.Enabled = !isLocked;
            cboLOB.Enabled = !isLocked;
            cboFullPart.Enabled = !isLocked;
            txtNotes.Enabled = !isLocked;
            txtFirmName.Enabled = !isLocked;
            txtUserName.Enabled = editMode == EmployeeEditMode.NewEmployee ? true : !isLocked;
            cboDomain.Enabled = !isLocked;
        }

        private void DatabaseCall(int queryNumber, string filter)
        {
            objConnect = new VM_DatabaseUtilities();
            if (queryNumber < 3)
                conString = Properties.Settings.Default.ccaDatabaseConnectionString_DEV;
            else
                conString = Properties.Settings.Default.corpIntegrationDatabaseConnectionString_DEV;

            objConnect.connectionString = conString;
            //BindingList<DropdownValues> ddVals = new BindingList<DropdownValues>();

            switch (queryNumber)
            {
                //Fill All Dropdowns
                case 0:
                    {
                        //Fill Domain Dropdown
                        cboDomain.DisplayMember = "Text";
                        cboDomain.ValueMember = "Value";

                        var domainItems = new[] { 
                            new { Text = "Wilton", Value = "W" }, 
                            new { Text = "Atlanta", Value = "A" }, 
                        };

                        cboDomain.DataSource = domainItems;

                        //Fill Full / Part Time Dropdown
                        cboFullPart.DisplayMember = "Text";
                        cboFullPart.ValueMember = "Value";


                        var FullPartItems = new[] { 
                            new { Text = "Part Time", Value = "0" }, 
                            new { Text = "Full Time", Value = "1" }, 
                        };

                        cboFullPart.DataSource = FullPartItems;

                        //Fill Type Selector Dropdown
                        sqlStatement = Properties.Settings.Default.cboTypeSelectRowSource;
                        objConnect.sqlQuery = sqlStatement;
                        ds = objConnect.GetConnection;

                        cboTypeSelect.DataSource = ds.Tables["Table_Data_1"];
                        cboTypeSelect.ValueMember = "EmpStatusID";
                        cboTypeSelect.DisplayMember = "EmpStatusDesc";

                        //Fill Company Dropdown
                        sqlStatement = Properties.Settings.Default.cboCompanyRowSource;
                        objConnect.sqlQuery = sqlStatement;
                        ds = objConnect.GetConnection;

                        cboCompany.DataSource = ds.Tables["Table_Data_1"];
                        cboCompany.ValueMember = "CoNum";
                        cboCompany.DisplayMember = "CoName";

                        //Fill LOB Dropdown
                        sqlStatement = Properties.Settings.Default.cboLOBRowSource;
                        objConnect.sqlQuery = sqlStatement;
                        ds = objConnect.GetConnection;

                        cboLOB.DataSource = ds.Tables["Table_Data_1"];
                        cboLOB.ValueMember = "CcaLOBID";
                        cboLOB.DisplayMember = "GPLOB";

                        //Fill Title Dropdown
                        sqlStatement = Properties.Settings.Default.cboTitleRowSource;
                        objConnect.sqlQuery = sqlStatement;
                        ds = objConnect.GetConnection;

                        cboTitle.DataSource = ds.Tables["Table_Data_1"];
                        cboTitle.ValueMember = "TitleID";
                        cboTitle.DisplayMember = "TitleName";

                        //Fill Type Dropdown
                        sqlStatement = Properties.Settings.Default.cboTypeRowSource;
                        objConnect.sqlQuery = sqlStatement;
                        ds = objConnect.GetConnection;

                        cboType.DataSource = ds.Tables["Table_Data_1"];
                        cboType.ValueMember = "EmpStatusID";
                        cboType.DisplayMember = "EmpStatusDesc";

                        //Fill PrimaryRole Dropdown
                        sqlStatement = Properties.Settings.Default.cboPRoleRowSource;
                        objConnect.sqlQuery = sqlStatement;
                        ds = objConnect.GetConnection;

                        cboPRole.DataSource = ds.Tables["Table_Data_1"];
                        cboPRole.ValueMember = "AssocType";
                        cboPRole.DisplayMember = "AssocDesc";

                        //Fill Location Dropdown
                        sqlStatement = Properties.Settings.Default.cboLocationRowSource;
                        objConnect.sqlQuery = sqlStatement;
                        ds = objConnect.GetConnection;

                        cboLocation.DataSource = ds.Tables["Table_Data_1"];
                        cboLocation.ValueMember = "LocationID";
                        cboLocation.DisplayMember = "LocationDesc";

                        //Fill SuperPrincipal Dropwdown
                        sqlStatement = Properties.Settings.Default.cboSuperPrincipalRowSource;
                        objConnect.sqlQuery = sqlStatement;
                        ds = objConnect.GetConnection;

                        cboSuperPrincipal.DataSource = ds.Tables["Table_Data_1"];
                        cboSuperPrincipal.ValueMember = "AssocId";
                        cboSuperPrincipal.DisplayMember = "Name";

                        break;
                    }
                //Fill Employee List
                case 1:
                    {
                        if (filter != "")
                            if (radActive.Checked)
                                filter = Properties.Settings.Default.activeFilter
                                    .PadLeft(Properties.Settings.Default.activeFilter.Length + 1)
                                    .PadRight(Properties.Settings.Default.activeFilter.Length + 1) + filter;
                            else
                                filter = Properties.Settings.Default.termedFilter
                                    .PadLeft(Properties.Settings.Default.termedFilter.Length + 1)
                                    .PadRight(Properties.Settings.Default.termedFilter.Length + 1) + filter;
                        else
                            if (radActive.Checked)
                                filter = Properties.Settings.Default.activeNoFilter
                                    .PadLeft(Properties.Settings.Default.activeNoFilter.Length + 1);
                            else
                                filter = Properties.Settings.Default.termedNoFilter
                                    .PadLeft(Properties.Settings.Default.termedNoFilter.Length + 1);

                        sqlStatement = Properties.Settings.Default.loadEmployeeList + filter + " ORDER BY EmployeeName ASC;";
                        objConnect.sqlQuery = sqlStatement;

                        ds = objConnect.GetConnection;

                        lstEmployees.DataSource = ds.Tables["Table_Data_1"];
                        lstEmployees.ValueMember = "AssocId";
                        lstEmployees.DisplayMember = "EmployeeName";

                        break;
                    }
                //Load individual employee data
                case 2:
                    {
                        sqlStatement = Properties.Settings.Default.loadAssociatesRowSource + filter + "'";
                        objConnect.sqlQuery = sqlStatement;
                        ds = objConnect.GetConnection;

                        //No row means no employee selected - just exit
                        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                            dRow = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0];

                        break;
                    }
                //Execute UpdateAssociate Sproc
                case 3:
                    {
                        bool isUpdated;
                        sqlStatement = "IndependentContractor.EmployeeUpdate";
                        isUpdated = objConnect.VM_ExecuteSproc(sqlStatement, filter);

                        break;
                    }
                //Execute NewAssociate Sproc
                case 4:
                    {
                        break;
                    }
            }
            maxRows = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
        }

        private Associate BuildAssociate()
        {
            Associate associate = new Associate();
            DateTime dateHolder;

            associate.AssocID = txtAssocId.Text ?? string.Empty;
            associate.FirstName = txtFname.Text ?? string.Empty;
            associate.LastName = txtLname.Text ?? string.Empty;
            associate.EmpNotes = txtNotes.Text ?? string.Empty;
            associate.AdpID = txtAdpId.Text ?? string.Empty;
            associate.FirmName = txtFirmName.Text ?? string.Empty;
            associate.UserName = txtUserName.Text ?? string.Empty;
            associate.FullPartTimeID = cboFullPart.SelectedValue == null ? string.Empty : cboFullPart.SelectedValue.ToString();
            associate.PrimaryRole = cboPRole.SelectedValue == null ? string.Empty : cboPRole.SelectedValue.ToString();
            associate.SystemDomain = cboDomain.SelectedValue == null ? string.Empty : cboDomain.SelectedText ?? string.Empty;
            associate.CoNum = cboCompany.SelectedValue == null ? string.Empty : cboCompany.SelectedValue.ToString();
            associate.LobID = cboLOB.SelectedValue == null ? string.Empty : cboLOB.SelectedValue.ToString();
            associate.Location = cboLocation.SelectedValue == null ? string.Empty : cboLocation.SelectedValue.ToString();
            associate.TitleID = cboTitle.SelectedValue == null ? string.Empty : cboTitle.SelectedValue.ToString();
            associate.SuperPrincipal = cboSuperPrincipal.SelectedValue == null ? string.Empty : cboSuperPrincipal.SelectedValue.ToString();
            associate.EmployeeTypeID = cboType.SelectedValue == null ? string.Empty : cboType.SelectedValue.ToString();

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtHireDate.Text))
            {
                DateTime.TryParse(txtHireDate.Text, out dateHolder);
                associate.HireDate = dateHolder.ToString("o");
            }
            else
            {
                associate.HireDate = "1900-01-01T00:00:00";
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtContractEnd.Text))
            {
                DateTime.TryParse(txtContractEnd.Text, out dateHolder);
                associate.ContractEndDate = dateHolder.ToString("o");
            }
            else
            {
                associate.ContractEndDate = "1900-01-01T00:00:00";
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtTerminationDate.Text))
            {
                DateTime.TryParse(txtTerminationDate.Text, out dateHolder);
                associate.TerminationDate = dateHolder.ToString("o");
            }
            else
            {
                associate.TerminationDate = "1900-01-01T00:00:00";
            }

            return associate;
            }


        #endregion

    }
 }
```

Comment: Have you heard of the *Model-View-Presenter* pattern?

Comment: No I have not heard of that - does that cover what is going on here and if I implemented it would that require an entire rewrite of the application?

Comment: Not rewrite, *refactor* - but that's what you're after, right? I hope you get awesome reviews! =)

Comment: What is your goal?  Why does this needs refactoring?

Comment: My goal was to frankly finish this application as it was put on hold and the original author recently quit.  I am new to developing full apps from the ground up and I thought that some of this buisiness logic should be decoupled from the form layer.  The more I look at it and I wonder if it is ok the way it is as all of those methods act on form objects.  Do you think its OK to leave this form class as is and just move on to completing the project?

Comment: No, it's doing *way* too much. Why is a Form doing database stuff directly, for example?

Comment: The database call doesn't make a connection. I have a database class that does that.  DatabaseCall makes an object of the database utilities class that handles all of that.  Maybe my naming convention doesn't work. But still I'm sure it should be refactored.

Comment: But you have a DataSet and DataRow directly in your class, and parse the rows. This class shouldn't know about that.

Comment: In that case how do I apply values from a dataset as text box values or as combobox data source?  That is what prompted me to open this question.   In my form code I shouldn't be saying cboWhatever.datasource = dataset?